# Prove that the distance of a centroid to a plane is the arithmetic mean of the distances of the vertexes of a triangle to that plane

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I tried to use the fact that the centroid divides the median in a ratio of $2:1$ and using similar triangles, but I got stuck.

Comment: can you write down a formula please?

Comment: Do you mean "the distance of a centroid **of a given triangle** to a plane"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up a coordinate system so that the triangle has one vertex at (0, 0, 0), a second vertex at (a, 0, 0), and the third vertex at (b, c, 0). Take the given plane to be px+ qy+ rz= s.  The centroid of that triangle is ((a+b)/3, c/3, 0).  A normal vector to the plane is .  Determine the line through the centroid in the direction of the normal vector and find where that line intersects the given plane.  Find the length of that line segment.

Then do the same with each of the three vertices to determine their distances from the plane and average them.

Answer (score 0):

Let the plane be the $x,y$ plane. Let  the three vertices have $z$ coordinates $u,v,w$. Then the centroid has $z$ coordinate $\frac{u+v+w}{3}$, as required.